# install virtualenv using pip or pip3?

Tags: pip, homebrew

I used brew to install both python2 and python3

```
brew install python
brew install python3
```

I noticed that there are pip and pip3 so which pip should I use to create virtualenv

`pip install virtualenv` or `pip3 install virtualenv`

Answer (score 8):

Use `pip install virtualenv` to create a `python` env and `pip3 install virtualenv` to install a `python3` env

The difference is required because if you use `pip install virtualenv` and need `python3` packages, you will get all kinds of errors!

UPDATE (2020-03-12):
With python3 you can also use

`python3 -m venv {directory}`

where `{directory}` is the path of/to your virtualenv.

Comment: so I did both `pip install virtualenv` and `pip3 install virtualenv` but there seems to be only one `virtualenv` so how can I know if that virtualenv is the one created by pip or pip3

Comment: No. What version your virtual environment will have is specified as argument, when actually making the env, like: `virtualenv -p python3 my_venv` or `virtualenv -p python2 my_venv`, regardless how the virtualenv package was installed. Furthermore checkout this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361190/do-we-need-pip-and-pip3

Comment: How to activate the virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#activators - `source bin/activate`

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

This doesn't create any virtual environment. That installs `virtualenv` program, that is used in order to create virtual environments.

What is the default python version that your virtual environment will have is specified as an argument, when actually making the env, like:

```
virtualenv -p python3 my_venv
```

or

```
virtualenv -p python2 my_venv
```

regardless on  how the virtualenv package was installed.

Furthermore checkout [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361190/do-we-need-pip-and-pip3)

Answer (score 2):

Your second question:"how can I know if that virtualenv is the one created by pip or pip3?"

-> You can activate the virtual environment with source bin/activate(first cd in the folder of the environment) When you are sure you are in the virtual environment, type "python --version". You can also check which python is active in the environment by typing "which python". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same question in mind and after searching and seeking advice, I've found the following insights:

- **pip:** Mainly associated with Python 2.x. It installs packages for the default Python version, which could be Python 2.7 on older systems.
- **pip3:** Specifically for Python 3.x. Using pip3 ensures package installation for Python 3, regardless of the default version.

Reasons for separate commands:

1. **Compatibility:** Python 2 and 3 differ significantly. Mixing packages can cause errors. Separate commands prevent conflicts.
2. **Clarity:** Explicitly using pip3 indicates your intention to work with Python 3, especially when both versions are present.

Therefore, for all newly project we need to run

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```